# Python string split by template

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm new in Python and I struggle with a probably an easy problem for all of you out there and maybe you could help me please

Basically I would need a function that reads a continuous string and break it as following: first 5 characters, inserts comma, next 6 characters, inserts comma, next 6 characters, inserts comma, inserts new line and then repeats

The problem: 
my string is:

```
"CARMD000000000003FEFFE000004000004BCCXT000009000025BBT01000035000025"
```

I need to divide this string into comma by following rule: `5-6-6 \n`

Expected result:

```
CARMD,000000,000003, 

FEFFE,000004,000004, 

BCCXT,000009,000025,

BBT01,000035,000025,
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

text = "CARMD000000000003FEFFE000004000004BCCXT000009000025BBT01000035000025"
match = re.findall(r'([A-Z]{5})(\d{6})(\d{6})', text)
lines = [','.join(item) for item in match]
print(*lines, sep='\n')
```

out:

```
CARMD,000000,000003
FEFFE,000004,000004
BCCXT,000009,000025
```

use regex to match text, will return a list of tuple:

```
[('CARMD', '000000', '000003'), ('FEFFE', '000004', '000004'), ('BCCXT', '000009', '000025')]
```

than use list comprehension to construct a list, each element in list is string, concatenated by the tuple using `','`.

lines:

```
['CARMD,000000,000003', 'FEFFE,000004,000004', 'BCCXT,000009,000025']
```

Comment: This Solution doesn't save the final string into a variable. It just prints it out. I guess that's good if you only want it for one-time use.

Comment: @Cheyn Shmuel i store data in list 'lines'

Answer (score 1):

*"One-line"* solution using `re.findall()` and `str.join()` functions:

```
s = "CARMD000000000003FEFFE000004000004BCCXT000009000025BBT01000035000025"
chunks = ',\n'.join(','.join(t) for t in re.findall(r'(\w{5})(\w{6})(\w{6})', s))

print(chunks)
```

The output:

```
CARMD,000000,000003,
FEFFE,000004,000004,
BCCXT,000009,000025,
BBT01,000035,000025
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `regex` is using list slicing with a for loop like below:

```
>>> s = 'CARMD000000000003FEFFE000004000004BCCXT000009000025BBT01000035000025'
>>> 
>>> for i in range(len(s) / 17):
...     temp = s[i*17:i*17+17]
...     print '{}, {}, {},'.format(temp[:5], temp[5:11], temp[11:17])
...
CARMD, 000000, 000003,
FEFFE, 000004, 000004,
BCCXT, 000009, 000025,
BBT01, 000035, 000025,
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple program like this should do the trick:

```
s = "CARMD000000000003FEFFE000004000004BCCXT000009000025BBT01000035000025"
new_s = ''
while s:
    for x in (5, 6, 6):
        new_s += s[:x]
        s = s[x:]
        new_s += ','
    new_s += '\n'

print(new_s)
```

output:

```
CARMD,000000,000003,
FEFFE,000004,000004,
BCCXT,000009,000025,
BBT01,000035,000025,
```

I found a nested loop efficient.